# How do I set my django debug=False and show 404 on the web when there is error?

Tags: python, django, web, heroku

My settings.py code:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', '') != 'False'
```

My .bash_profile:

```
# Django test deploy
 export SECRET_KEY='67bd6db221e2be1b5b16cb70b79d3bbee8928d9053a8eb32'
 export DJANGO_DEBUG="False"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default 404 page. You first create a 404 template and respective view. After which in urls.py you add

```
handler404 = 'mysite.views.my_custom_page_not_found_view'
```

This is for page not found error, for other error codes like 500,etc do accordingly.
Read the official documentation here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/